# Enable/disable bluetooth without sudo

Tags: debian, bluetooth, bluez

I'm using Debian and I would like to enable/disable the Bluetooth without sudo.

Bluetooth is working perfect for me via `bluez` and I manage it through "blueman-applet".

When I disable it, I have to run the following commands to enable it again:

```
modprobe btusb
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

I'm gonna make a script to toggle the bluetooth functionality, so my idea is to modify my sudoers files (`sudo visudo`) to add the following lines:

```
USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/modprobe btusb
USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl enable bluetooth.service
USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

I wonder if there's an another command to achieve this, without editing the sudoers file. I also would like to know if this idea is safe.